# Can I do a conditional sum in a create table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DATABASE VIDEO_CLUB;

USE VIDEO_CLUB;

CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
 ID_cliente int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 DNI_cliente varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 nombre_cliente varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 apellido_cliente varchar(40) NOT NULL,
 direccion_cliente varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 telefono_cliente varchar(15) NOT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE ALQUILER(
 ID_alquiler int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 ID_cliente int(10) NOT NULL,
 fecha_alquiler datetime NOT NULL, 
 fecha_devolucion datetime,
 FOREIGN KEY (ID_cliente) REFERENCES cliente(ID_cliente) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I need to create a column in 'cliente' that adds 1 to itself as long as 'fecha_devolucion' is NULL and
subtracts 1 from itself as long as 'fecha_devolucion' isn't NULL. I don't know if that's possible. This is my first question in StackOverFlow and I hope you can enlighten me. Thanks!!

Comment: one of them is probably NOT NULL. At first, I thought this question is about generated column. turned out need to join both tables too. now Im confused too hahaha

Comment: Both conditions about fecha_devolucion are the same in your question. About your question, it seems a bit strange for me, because you want the creation of a column at Cliente depends upon the value of a tuple column at Alquiler. Maybe the column should be created anyway at Cliente and you create a trigger to control changing values.

Comment: *I don't know if that's possible.* This is impossible. Generated column may refer the current row columns values only. But you may easily obtain the data which you need in the query, or, if your data is static (rows may be added only, not updated/deleted), use trigger logic (BEFORE INSERT).

Comment: Thanks for helping me guys.